Recursive relation for power series coefficients
I wish to find a recurrence relation involving the coefficients of the power series of $\mathrm{exp}(x^2/2 + x^3/3)$. This happens to be an exponential generating function and so via a combinatorial argument I know that the coefficients $a_n$ satisfy
$$a_n = (n-1)a_{n-1} + (n-1)(n-2)a_{n-2}$$
How would I find this relation if I did not recognize the function as an EGF?
Clearly $a_n = f^{(n)}(0)$, but computing $n^{th}$ derivatives of this function does not seem easy.
Edit: The indices on the right side of the recurrence relation given above are off by 1, as pointed out in the comments.

Computing $f^{(n)}(0)$ gives me the series $(a_0,...,a_n)= (1,0,1,2,3,20,55,210,1225)$, so e.g. $a_4 = 3$, but $3a_3 + 32a_2 = 32+61=12$. I think it should be $(n-1)a_{n-2} + (n-1)(n-2)a_{n-3}$

There may be even more general frameworks, but the following will work to give a recurrence for the exponential of any polynomial. The punchline is that the derivative of the exponential of a polynomial is just a polynomial times that exponential.
So, if we write $$ f(x) = \exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3}\right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!} x^n. $$ Then we can differentiate  to get $$ f'(x) = (x+x^2)\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3}\right) = (x+x^2) \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!}x^n. $$ Now we re-index the first term to get $$ x\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!}x^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!}x^{n+1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_{n-1}}{(n-1)!}x^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{na_{n-1}}{n!}x^n $$ And we re-index the second term to get $$ x^2\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!}x^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!}x^{n+2} = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{a_{n-2}}{(n-2)!}x^n = \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{n(n-1)a_{n-2}}{n!}x^n. $$ Adding these we get that $$ f'(x) =  a_0x + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{na_{n-1}+n(n-1)a_{n-2}}{n!}x^n. $$ But we can also differentiate $f(x)$ as a series directly to get $$ f'(x) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n!} x^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\frac{a_n}{n!} x^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{(n-1)!} x^{n-1} =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_{n+1}}{n!} x^{n}$$ where the last step was just a re-indexing. We can then compare these two expressions, which have to have the same coefficients, giving us that for $n \geq 2$ we have $$ a_{n+1} = na_{n-1} + n(n-1)a_{n-2} $$ which, up to re-indexing, is, I think, the correct version of the recursion as given by @ConnFus
